# How does Azure Deployment switch works from staging to production?

Tags: azure

I heard that there will be no session time out happens when the deployment switch happens in Azure from staging to production. Is my understanding correct?. If so how Azure handles internally this switch?.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what *switch form staging to production* you're talking about. Because you could use Deployment Slots like this, but it is not recommended to have a full-blown Staging environment as a slot on your App Service. Since these slots run on the same App Service Plan as Production, heavy load on Staging could hurt Production performance.

I tend to think of it more as *a 'Pre-Production' environment* using a Deployment Slot where you can do some last checks (smoke test) before you release the new version of your application into the wild.

I would think sessions are managed internally since the two slots run on the same App Service Plan, making this a relative simple scenario.

**Documentation**

> Deploying an app to a slot first and swapping it into production ensures that all instances of the slot are warmed up before being swapped into production. This eliminates downtime when you deploy your app. The traffic redirection is seamless, and no requests are dropped as a result of swap operations.

Find more information about using slots here: [Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing)